# systemsettings and related printer issues in 22.04

Tags: permissions, printing

In the process of debugging an issue with trying to print a test page, I found the following:

- printing from all my various applications - graphics, office, etc, works fine under my non-privileged user id / normal user.
- printing a test page from systemsettings run as normal user from menu fails with the "Unable to open print file: Permission denied" error, and printer itself hangs, apparently trying to print; however, printer ink levels are correctly displayed, and queue can be managed.
- running systemsettings from the command line, as root, results in:

  1. much improved graphics in system settings (background is light, not dark, ink levels displayed more clearly, etc)
  2. printing the test page works fine

Since I have a workaround (running systemsettings from command line as root), this is currently non-critical, but it may be causing confusion for folks setting up printers then trying to create a test page.

Answer (score 0):

I have just experienced this in kubuntu 22.04.01. I could print from applications but could not print a test page from System Settings - the print queue item showed "Unable to open print file: Permission denied".

Adding myself to group `lp` with `sudo usermod -a -G lp <user>` fixed it for me (I was already a member of `lpadmin` but not `lp` for some reason).

Comment: Thank you! yes, that resolved it for me as well. gui is better as root, for whatever reason, but functionally this resolved the issue. thanks again!